# Docker port forwarding with dual network interface

Tags: networking, docker, cloud

I have totally no idea about how to handle this situation. First of all, I would like explain the scenario that i'm having right now.

I have a swarm cluster and 5 consul container with a overlay network which subnet is 10.10.10.0 . There for my consul container would get the overlay network with 10.10.10.10, 10.10.10.11, 10.10.10.12, 10.10.10.13, 10.10.10,14 .

This swarm cluster was hosting in a virtual machine in openstack. The host has a private ip with 10.176.33.74 and allocate with a floating ip 10.176.2.170.

The consul agent inside the host join and gossip using standard RPC port 8300.

I have a use case for the consul agent which hosting outside of openstack network to connect into swarm cluster consul. Eventually, the node from outside must connect through floating ip and I understand it's not possible to connect to the overlay network directly.

In this case, I have an idea to create second interface for every docker container and this interface responsible to handle port forwarding. If incoming request is listening to port 8300, it should forward to consul:8300 (consul domain would recognize in swarm load balancer).

Is this way possible, and I have no idea how to do the port forwarding within an network interface to another interface.

Appreciate if someone could provide a guidance.

Comment: Hmmmn... maybe you can set up the secondary network interfaces and for the port forwarding you'll need iptables for sure.

Comment: Maybe it's only a way.